# How to configure geany to upload project at site?

Tags: ide, geany

I work on one website. I was using quanta+, but now i have to use slow pc, so i've found lightweight IDE - geany. But i miss one feature from quanta, upload project to web.

Is possible to do this with geany?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply mean using version control, then there is a plug-in for that already.

http://plugins.geany.org/geanyvc.html

I have not used it yet, so I do not know how effective it is.